# Как сделать цикл от 0001 до 239000

Tags: javascript, php

Есть номера бланков от ЕН0001 До ЕН259899. Как реализовать цикл так, чтобы в *0001* нули не исчезали? Там может быть от 4 до 5 нулей.

Comment: от того что в начале нули стоят цикл не изменится. Ищите функции дополнения строк до нужной длины, либо форматирования чисел.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [JS | Дополнительные нули перед числом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1148276/js-%d0%94%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы дополнить строку нуля в начале - можно использовать **[str_pad](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.str-pad.php)**.

Например:

```
echo str_pad(1, 10, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);  // 0000000001
```

дополнит строку 10-ю нулями перед цифрой 1

---

Зная это, можно организовывать просто цикл от 1, дополняя нулями впереди по необходимому количеству

---

для JS есть аналог:

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Answer (score 0):

Как уже сказал [@teran](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1387882/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB-%D0%BE%D1%82-0001-%D0%B4%D0%BE-239000#comment2467017_1387882), цикл вам не поможет, нужно форматировать вывод значения.

---

Относительно [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)

Есть встроенная функция [`.padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) | [поддержка](https://caniuse.com/?search=padStart).

```js
console.log('1'.padStart(4, 0));
console.log('14'.padStart(4, 0));
console.log('321'.padStart(4, 0));
console.log('1232'.padStart(4, 0));
```

---

Ну или *самопал*:

```js
function func(num, len) {
  return num >= 10**len ? num : (10**len + num+'').substr(1);
}

console.log(func(1, 4));
console.log(func(14, 4));
console.log(func(321, 4));
console.log(func(1232, 4));
```

В первый параметр передаётся число которое нужно форматировать, во второй длину строчки, например `func(1, 2)` - `01`, `func(134, 5)` - `00134` и т.п.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart  ....... быстрее и лучше

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, угу, только что загуглил, благодаря вашему ответу на PHP, в целом можно юзать и его, но `Experimental`

Comment: На самом деле уже давно можно https://caniuse.com/?search=padStart   .... Это доступно ещё с ES2017